# Transactional TestNG test causes Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: spring, postgresql, blob, testng, transactional

I am aware of the fact that Postgres requires a transaction when handling large objects. What is weird to me, is that I get this error even if I am within a transaction - or at least I think I am. I am running my code within a TestNG test case like this:

```
public class MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests
```

This is my test method:

```
public void insertAndRetrieve() throws Exception {

    MasterpriceFile expectedMasterpriceFile = repository.save("A test file.txt", "text/plain", new ByteArrayInputStream("This is a test file".getBytes()));
    MasterpriceFile actualMasterpriceFile = repository.getById(expectedMasterpriceFile.getId());
    assertThat(actualMasterpriceFile).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expectedMasterpriceFile);

}
```

And here is the save method within my repository (the one I would like to test):

```
public MasterpriceFile save(final String filename, final String contentType, final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    try {
        // NOTE: Below code is postgres specific. Needs to be changed if DB vendor changes.
        ConnectionHandle connectionHandle = (ConnectionHandle) getTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
        PGConnection connection = (PGConnection) connectionHandle.getInternalConnection();

        LargeObjectManager largeObjectManager = connection.getLargeObjectAPI();
        long contentOid = largeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.READWRITE);

        LargeObject largeObject = largeObjectManager.open(contentOid);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, largeObject.getOutputStream());
        largeObject.close();

        MasterpriceFile masterpriceFile = new MasterpriceFile();
        masterpriceFile.setContentType(contentType);
        masterpriceFile.setCreationDate(DateTime.now());
        masterpriceFile.setContentOid(contentOid);
        masterpriceFile.setFilename(filename);

        masterpriceFile.setId(updateAndReturnSimpleKeyAsLong(INSERT, "id",
                convert(masterpriceFile.getCreationDate()),
                masterpriceFile.getContentOid(),
                masterpriceFile.getFilename(),
                masterpriceFile.getContentType()));

        return masterpriceFile;         
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw getTemplate().getExceptionTranslator().translate("store masterprice file", null, e);
    }

}
```

Running the test gives me the following result:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: store masterprice file; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [25P01]; error code [0]; Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.save_aroundBody4(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.java:73)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc$AjcClosure5.run(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.save(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.java:44)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest.insertAndRetrieve_aroundBody0(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest.java:28)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest$AjcClosure1.run(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest.insertAndRetrieve(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbcTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:301)
    at solve.scm.repository.jdbc.MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.save_aroundBody4(MasterpriceFileRepositoryJdbc.java:52)
    ... 44 more
```

Can anyone tell me if what is wrong in this case? It looks like I am within a transaction

```
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66
```

So why does Postgres think that I am not?

This is the method in postgres that causes the stacktrace:

```
public long createLO(int mode) throws SQLException
{
    if (conn.getAutoCommit())
        throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode."),
                                PSQLState.NO_ACTIVE_SQL_TRANSACTION);
    FastpathArg args[] = new FastpathArg[1];
    args[0] = new FastpathArg(mode);
    return fp.getOID("lo_creat", args);
}
```

Comment: In most cases `bytea` is a better choice than large objects for a "BLOB" type column

Comment: I used bytea first, but then it was not possible to stream data to the database without knowing the length of the stream in advance which I do not. And I most certainly will not read the whole stream into memory. I could stream it to disk first, but it seams like a lot of extra processing just to get bytea to work.

Comment: Ah, ok. That *is* indeed one of the cases where large objects make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the following codeline:

```
ConnectionHandle connectionHandle = (ConnectionHandle) getTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
```

into this:

```
ConnectionHandle connectionHandle = (ConnectionHandle) DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getTemplate().getDataSource());
```

It looks like DataSourceUtils.getConnection retrieves the *current* connection which participates in the transaction, whereas getTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection() returns a new connection.